# How does iter() work, it's giving "TypeError: iter(v, w): v must be callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, typeerror

What is the problem with this code?

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for val in iter(l, 4):
    print (val)
```

It returns

```
TypeError: iter(v, w): v must be callable
```

Why does **callable(list)** return **True** but **callable(l)** does not?

**EDIT**
What method should be preferred here:

2. manual breaks
3. hundred others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `iter` help:

> iter(...)
>       iter(collection) -> iterator
>       iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator
>
> ```
> Get an iterator from an object.  In the first form, the argument must
> supply its own iterator, or be a sequence.
> In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.
> ```

You are mixing two variants of `iter` function. First one accepts collections, second accepts two arguments - function and sentinel value. You're trying to pass collection **and** sentinel value, which is wrong.

Short note: you can get a lot of interesting info from python's built-in `help` function. Simply type in python's console `help(iter)` and you'll get documentation on it.

> Why does callabe(list) return true but callable(l) does not?

Because `list` is function which returns new list object. Function is callable (that's what function does - it gets called), while instance which this function returns - new list object - is not.

Comment: nice but I am still stuck on the **callable(list)** vs **callable(list_instance)**
why they are different?

Comment: Actually, `list` is not a function, it's a type. Every function is callable, but not every callable is a function.

Comment: @thg435 the `list` has to implement `__init__` method so it can initialize new list objects. but how does this type become callable - by implementation of the `__call__` method? or implementation of `__init__` make it callable?

Comment: @aga: no, the type `type` implements `__call__`, that's why all types (=classes) are callable. Not their instances.

Comment: @thg435 thanks for the explanation, seems like I have a mess in my head about types and classes in python. :) I'll read about it today's evening.

Answer (score 5):

When called with two arguments, `iter` takes a callable and a sentinel value. It's behavior is like it was implemented so:

```
def iter2args(f, sentinel):
    value = f()
    while value != sentinel:
        yield value
        value = f()
```

What gets passed in as `f` must be *callable*, which just means that you can call it like a function. The `list` builtin is a `type` object, which you use to create new list instances, by calling it like a function:

```
>>> list('abcde')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

The list `l` you passed in is an existing list instance, which can't be used like a function:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> l(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    l(3)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Thus, there is a large and important difference between the `list` type object and list instances, which shows up when using with `iter`.

To iterate through a list until a sentinel is reached, you can use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
import itertools
for val in itertools.takewhile(l, lambda x: x!= 4):
    print(val)
```

Comment: The last example causes the error "'function' object is not iterable" for python 3...

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the second value being pass (a so called sentinel value), this ensures that the object being iterated over is a callable ie. a function.
So for every iteration that `iter()`does it calls `__next__()` on the object being passed.

`iter()` has two distinct behaviors,

- without a sentinel value
- with a sentinel value

The example in the documentation is great for understanding it

```
with open("mydata.txt") as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, "STOP"): #fp.readline is a function here.
        process_line(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter

When second argument in `iter` is present then first argument is treated very differently. It is supposed to be a function which is called in each step. If it returns sentinel (i.e. the second argument), then the iteration stops. For example:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

index = -1
def fn():
    global index
    index += 1
    return l[index]

for val in iter(fn, 4):
    print (val)
```

**EDIT:** If you want to just loop over a list and stop when you see a sentinel, then I recommend doing simply this:

```
for val in l:
    # main body
    if val == 4:
        break
```

Comment: so what is the best way of do a iteration over that list using a sentinel value?

Comment: @new-kid If you want to use the `iter(callable, sentinel)` to do that, just use `iter(the_list.__next__, 4)`. [in python2 replace `__next__` with `next`]

Comment: @Bakuriu that is great. But should I prefer using `iter(the_list.__next__,4)` or manual breaks?

Comment: @new-kid I find `iter(the_list.__next__,4)` ugly and not easy to read unlike breaks. Also "private" methods (i.e. those starting with `__`) should not be used directly. But it is a matter of choice.

Comment: @new-kid I agree with freakish: just use a `break`. By the way, I just realized my suggestion wasn't 100% correct because `list`s do *not* have a `__next__`. You'd have to do: `iter(iter(the_list).__next__, 4)` which is really ugly.

Comment: saw that last comment of yours quite late.
gonna delete that ugliness from question.

Comment: @new-kid There are two additional things: 1) In Python2.x it is `next` while in Python3.x it is `__next__`. Also I've done some tests (empty loops) and `iter` is around 50% slower in Python2.x and around 25% slower in Python3.x. It probably depends on machine and many other things. However it will definitely be a bit slower.

Comment: @freakish I'd *expect* it to be slower. Note that when doing `for element in iter(callable, sentinel)` the interpreter has to perform a *generic* call (`PyObject_Call`) for each iteration, while using `for element in iterable` the interpreter can safely call `PyObject_Next` on the iterable, without the overhead of the generic call. Note however that using `iter(callable, sentinel)` is *faster* than the equivalent solution using `while True` + calling the function and explicit `break` (which I often see used).

Comment: @Bakuriu Such `while` construction is an overkill, since you can just simply put a body of the function inside it (and in that case I've tested that it is 2x faster). Besides the difference seems to be extremely small. From my tests it's just around 1% faster.

Comment: @freakish No you can't because your boss will kill you. If you could what would be the point of functions at all? You can simply copy-paste their body everytime you call them (except for recursion, even though you *could* still emulate it via explicit stack). Also in that case the speed up is **not** due to the `while` being faster but to the code being *different*. You aren't simply avoiding a lookup you are completely removing a function call. Besides I meant code like `while True: chunk = function() if not chunk: break # DO OTHER STUFF`. You can see it *plenty* of times.

Comment: @Bakuriu You misunderstand. I don't see any reason for doing this, because it is just a reimplementation of `__next__`. If you have `__next__`, then you simply do `for ... in ...` (which is more efficient then `for ... in iter(...)`. If you don't need such function, then you put its body inside a loop. In practice I've never seen `iter` being used in such way.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that classes are objects in Python.

```
>>> callable(list)
True
```

Means that *list itself* is callable, rather than instances of it being callable. As you've seen, they aren't:

```
>>> callable([])
False
```

In fact, all classes in Python are callable - if they don't have literals like `list`, this is the usual way to instantiate them. Consider:

```
def MyClass:
     pass

a = MyClass()
```

The last line calls the `MyClass` class object, which creates an instance - so, `MyClass` must be callable. But you wouldn't expect that *instance* to be callable, since `MyClass` itself doesn't define an `__call__`.

On the other hand, the class *of* `MyClass` (ie, its metaclass, `type`) *does*:

```
>>> type.__call__
<slot wrapper '__call__' of 'type' objects>
```

which is what makes `MyClass` callable.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does callabe(list) return true but callable(l) does not?

Because `list` is  a Python builtin function while `l` is a list.

Comment: so is **l** not an instance of the **list** class?

Comment: @new-kid Your comment doesn't make any sense. `list` is a class and *all* classes are callable (you call them to create instances). The instances need not be callable. Think about it: what should `[1,2,3]()` do? or `1()`? The `int` class is callable but `int` instances aren't.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> l_it = iter(l)
>>> while True:
...     next_val = next(l_it, None)
...     if not next_val:
...             break
...     print(next_val)
```